limit context token on document retrieval chains
Code
import os
from qdrant_client import QdrantClient

from langchain.vectorstores import Qdrant
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.chains import create_retrieval_chain
from langchain.schema import HumanMessage, SystemMessage, AIMessage
from langchain.chains.combine_documents import create_stuff_documents_chain
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder

from langchain_core.runnables import RunnablePassthrough

from langchain.callbacks import get_openai_callback

class ConversationChatManagement():

    def _get_existing_vector_store(self, collection_identity):
        qdrant_host = os.environ.get('QDRANT_HOST', 'qdrant-host-set')
        new_client = QdrantClient(host=qdrant_host, port=6333)

        embeddings=OpenAIEmbeddings()
        return Qdrant(
            client=new_client,
            collection_name=collection_identity,
            embeddings=embeddings,
        )

    def _create_prompt_template(self):
        SYSTEM_TEMPLATE = """
        Answer the user's questions based on the below context and message history.
        If the context doesn't contain any relevant information to the question, don't make something up and just say "I don't know":

        <context>
        {context}
        </context>
        """

        messages = [
            (
                "system",
                SYSTEM_TEMPLATE,
            ),
            MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="messages")
        ]

        return ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages)

    def chat_conversation(self, message_content: str, collection_identity, target_conversation, llm_client: ChatOpenAI):
        # Basically, a list of `HumanMessage, SystemMessage, AIMessage` objects.
        # Representing the conversation history fetched from database..
        history_messages = self._fetch_conversation_history(target_conversation)

        prompt_template = self._create_prompt_template()
        document_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm_client, prompt_template)

        def parse_retriever_input(params: Dict):
            return params["messages"][-1].content

        # Add vector store into document chain to become retrieval chain.
        existing_vector_store = self._get_existing_vector_store(collection_identity)
        retriever = existing_vector_store.as_retriever()
        retrieval_chain = RunnablePassthrough.assign(
            context=parse_retriever_input | retriever,
        ).assign(
            answer=document_chain,
        )

        docs = retriever.invoke(message_content)

        messages = history_messages + [HumanMessage(content=message_content)] 
        message_stream = retrieval_chain.stream({
            "context": docs,
            "messages": messages
        })


Code was mostly reference from here


The Issue
For large documents, it will return an error about the maximum context length:
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "This model's maximum context length is 8192 tokens. However, your messages resulted in 8367 tokens. Please reduce the length of the messages.", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': 'messages', 'code': 'context_length_exceeded'}}


I am using langchain===0.1.9, openai===1.5.0 and langchain-community===0.0.24. Currently, upgrading or downgrading is not a viable option since it might result in too many breaking changes in the project, which might not be resolved in time.


Explored Solutions
1. ReduceDocumentsChain
The best reference I saw was in ReduceDocumentsChain's example (link in the header).
However, the problem is that the example code uses a ton of deprecated, non-working code that does not work in the version I am using:

OpenAI was deprecated in 0.0.10. When I attempted the example with my versions, this causes the codebase to break.
LLMChain was deprecated in 0.1.17; Attempting to replace the input object of OpenAI with ChatOpenAI causes it to break.


Admittedly, even if this example works with my version, I am confused on how I would attach the message history into this as well...

2. ConversationalRetrievalChain
Contains a max_tokens_limit which I thought I could use. But it's deprecated, and requires question_generator: LLMChain, which is also deprecated... (Recall LLMChain doesn't work with ChatOpenAI)
create_history_aware_retriever with create_retrieval_chain, as suggested by the documentation, doesn't seem to provide any sort of functionality/parameters to limit token length.

Admittedly, I am new to LangChain API.Hence, I suspect might be a design issue as well... (wrong chain/tools, or wrong prompts, etc).But I am unable to clearly identify what the problem/solution is.

Apparently for my case, the issue lied with how I inserted document/texts into the Qdrant Store:
doc = [
    Document(
        page_content=file_contents # This was the ENTIRE document worth of content in string, not good lol
    )
]

vector_ids = qdrant_collection.add_documents(doc)

I inserted the entire document directly into the Qdrant vector-store without splitting it up.This resulted in retrieval documents searches to contain the entire document, which would easily exceed the token limit.

I fixed it by just using LangChain's CharacterTextSplitter to chunk the texts instead, before storing into the Qdrant vector-store.
def _get_chunked_text(text):
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
        separator='\n',
        chunk_size=1000,
        chunk_overlap=150,
        length_function=len
    )
    return text_splitter.split_text(text)

chunked_text = _get_chunked_text(file_contents)
vector_ids = qdrant_collection.add_texts(chunked_text)


Though this 'solution' for me doesn't actually answer the original question of trying to limit the token size on the context window.As such I won't flag mine as the correct solution, and keep this question open...

I had a similar issue and I solved by using context compression: https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/retrievers/contextual_compression/
here is a code sample:
# Import necessary modules
from operator import itemgetter
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnablePassthrough
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.retrievers import ContextualCompressionRetriever
from langchain.retrievers.document_compressors import LLMChainExtractor
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings

# Suppress warnings for cleaner output
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Initialize embeddings function using OpenAI's model
embedding_function = OpenAIEmbeddings()

# Create a Chroma vector store with a directory for persistence and the embedding function
db = Chroma(persist_directory='./commandites', embedding_function=embedding_function)

# Initialize a chat model from OpenAI with no randomness in responses (temperature=0)
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0)

# Create a document compressor using the initialized chat model
compressor = LLMChainExtractor.from_llm(llm)

# Turn the Chroma vector store into a retriever
retriever = db.as_retriever()

# Create a retriever that uses contextual compression
compression_retriever = ContextualCompressionRetriever(base_compressor=compressor, base_retriever=retriever)

# Define a chat prompt template for questions
template = """Respond to the following question based on this context:

{context}

Question: {question}
"""

# Create a chat prompt from the template
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template)


# Define a function to format documents
def format_docs(docs):
    return "\\n\\n".join(doc.page_content for doc in docs)

# Define a retriever and parser chain that formats and parses the response
final_rag_chain = (
    {"context": compression_retriever | format_docs, "question": RunnablePassthrough()} 
    | prompt
    | llm
    | StrOutputParser()
)

# Example question to invoke the chain with
question = "When did the scandal break out?"
result = final_rag_chain.invoke(question)
print(result)  # Output the result

